# In Qt,How to make triggered(bool checked=false) checked become true

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

When I click a toolBar,But checked is false
I want to know that how to make checked==true

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. Most possible questions are answered in  that documentation

Comment: You have to make the action checkable (property [QAction::checkable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#checkable-prop)). Then it can be checked/unchecked (e.g. by user interaction) and `checked` will reflect its current state.

Comment: Thank you Scheff's Cat,My problem have been solved!